# GIT: What is commits priority during merge?

Tags: git, branch

I wonder, what is the priority of picking commits during merge in the situation, described below.

I have `develop` branch.

```
D1 - D2 - D3
```

Then I created `release` branch from it and add some commits.

```
D1 - D2 - D3 - R4 - R5
```

In the meantime some commits to develop were added

```
D1 - D2 - D3 - D6
```

Then, I remove some commits from `release` branch using `git rebase -i HEAD~3`:

```
D1 - x - x - R4 - R5
```

---

How `release` branch will be merged to `develop` using `git merge --no-ff release`? I want to have it like this:

```
D1 - D2 - D3 - R4 - R5 - D6
```

And is there a possibility that I'll get merged branch with commits deletion?

```
D1 - x - x - R4 - R5 - D6
```

I am looking forward for explanations about "behind the scene" :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you did a `revert` in `release` it would revert those commits on a merge.  If you did a `rebase` it won't.  That's because `revert` shows you explicitly deleting them, and retaining that fact in the history.  `rebase` makes it look like those commits never happened in `release`, so there's no reason for the `merge` to delete them.

As far as priority, both branches have equal priority no matter what.  Going back to the last commit the branches have in common, if each branch changes something in different ways, git will show it as a merge conflict.  The only reason the `rebase` doesn't revert those commits is because you rewrote history to make it look like they were never present in the branch to begin with.

As an aside, you do realize you can test these things out in git, either in a clone or by being careful with your branches, in probably less time than it takes to ask a question?

Comment: Thank you for the explanation - it is really useful for me. As for your question - of course, I can test it. But this testing will not give me any explanation. And my goal was to understand, how things go under the coat. You gave me that tip - thank you very much ;)

Answer (score 4):

As an addition to the other answers:

> I wonder, what is the priority of picking commits during merge in the situation

Git normally does not have the notion of "priority" during merges. During a merge, all branches are equally important, and Git tries to combine the changes from all branches.

If there is a contradiction (such as different branches changing the same line in different ways), Git will not somehow let one branch "win", but will report a merge conflict.

This was actually a deliberate design decision. Linux talking about merging in Git:

> Linus: Me *personally*, I want to have something that is very repeatable and non-clever. 
>   Something I understand *or* tells me that it can't do it.

http://www.wincent.com/a/about/wincent/weblog/archives/2007/07/a_look_back_bra.php

So Git deliberately does not somehow cleverly try to figure out which branch is "more important" - it just leaves the decision to the user.

Comment: Nice input. Thank you very much for additional explanation!

Answer (score 1):

You seem to know `git-rebase`, so:

```
$ git checkout develop
$ git rebase -i D1 release
```

The interactive mode lets you pick and reorder the commits the way you want.

Comment: You mean, I should use this way instead of `git merge`?